# Kafka Mirror Maker failing to replicate __consumer_offset topic

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, mirroring, consumer

I am trying to make use of mirror maker to replicate `__consumer_offsets` topic along with other topics.

It is giving error as mentioned below.

> [2018-10-24 16:16:03,802] ERROR Error when sending message to topic
> __consumer_offsets with key: 16 bytes, value: 445 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: The request
> attempted to perform an operation on an invalid topic. [2018-10-24
> 16:16:03,828] ERROR Error when sending message to topic
> __consumer_offsets with key: 29 bytes, value: 754 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: The request
> attempted to perform an operation on an invalid topic.

Is there any way to resolve this?

In one of the confluent presentation in [SlideShare](https://www.slideshare.net/gwenshap/multidatacenter-kafka-strata-san-jose-2017) on slide21, it mentioned about **replicating offset topic** in multiple datacenters. Can someone tell me the possible way to achieve the same?

Or there is any other better way for backup and restore policy for Kafka.

Comment: In general, replicating the offsets topic is a bad idea unless you're guaranteed consumer group names are the same between both clusters as well as the offsets within the topics, especially if you are starting a mirror after the source topic's retention window. Besides, that slide didn't explicitly say you should do this

Comment: Yes, In my case consumer group names are the same and mirror maker, source and target cluster will be starting at the same time. All the topics in source and target will be having the same number of partitions. There will no consumer running in target cluster until the source is completely down.

Comment: How do you plan to move the consumed offsets of the second cluster back to the first after the first goes down? Note:  Sounds like you're trying to recreate Confluent Replicator, which is based on Kafka Connect, not MirrorMaker

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this in your *consumer.config*:

```
exclude.internal.topics=false
```

And add this in your *producer.config*:

```
client.id=__admin_client
```

Reason being, Producers cannot write to internal topics unless you declare `client.id=__admin_client` which is used by AdminClient.scala. Found here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6524

Comment: Thank You @amdelamar for your response. I'll test and update you back.

Comment: @AbhishekVerma did you test this out? I am having some issues by following this logic. More details here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54449324/kafka-mirror-maker-sync-consumer-offsets-topic-duplicates

Comment: @suraj_fale I verified this solution. It worked for me.

Comment: @suraj_fale  is this valid for MirrorMaker 2.0? I am facing the same issue, all the topics are being replicated except __consumer_offsets. I am using MirrorMaker 2.0 as a Kafka-connect connector.

Comment: @AmitYadav We haven't yet migrated to MirrorMaker 2.0 yet. But that's what my understanding was. Which Kafka version you are using btw?

Comment: @suraj_fale I'm using Kafka 2.8 with Mirrormaker 2.0. Would you mind sharing your config files?

Comment: @AmitYadav As I was saying, we are still on MirrorMaker 1.0 (if thats what we call it) with Kafka version 2.0.0. We are still having this issue for now. We want to first upgrade our cluster to new version.

Comment: @suraj_fale if I'm not getting it wrong, that means it's working with MirrorMaker 1.0 right? So would you mind sharing the '.config' files(after truncating the sensitive information of course)?