# Kafka Mirror Maker : Sync __consumer_offsets topic duplicates

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, disaster-recovery

Following to the solution mentioned here [kafka-mirror-maker-failing-to-replicate-consumer-offset-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967654/kafka-mirror-maker-failing-to-replicate-consumer-offset-topic). I was able to start mirror maker without any error across DC1(Live Kafka cluster) and DC2(Backup Kafka cluster) clusters.

Looks like it is also able to sync `__consumer_offsets` topic across DC2 cluster form DC1 cluster.

**Issue**

If I close down consumer for DC1 and point same consumer(same group_id) to DC2 it reads the same messages again even though mirror maker is able sync offsets for this topic and partitions.

I can see that LOG-END-OFFSET is showing correctly but CURRENT-OFFSET is still pointing to old causing LAG.

**Example**

- Mirror Maker is still running in DC2.
- Before consumer shut down in DC1

  ```
  //DC1  __consumer_offsets topic
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
  | TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG  |
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
  | gs.suraj.test.1 0          10626           10626           0    |
  | gs.suraj.test.1 2          10619           10619           0    |
  | gs.suraj.test.1 1          10598           10598           0    |
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
  ```
- Stop consumer in DC1
- Before consumer start up in DC2

  ```
  //DC2  __consumer_offsets topic
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
  | TOPIC           PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG  |
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
  | gs.suraj.test.1 0          9098            10614           1516 |
  | gs.suraj.test.1 2          9098            10614           1516 |
  | gs.suraj.test.1 1          9098            10615           1517 |
  +-----------------------------------------------------------------+
  ```

Because of this lag, when I start same consumer in DC2 in reads 4549 messages again, which should not happen as it is already read an commited in DC1 and mirror maker have sync `__consumer_offsets` topic from DC1 to DC2

Please let me know if I am missing anything in here.

Comment: this may be weird, but maybe the mirror maker is using a producer that doesn't fill his batch.size parameter, and even if it made a call to produce(), that message is still on his buffer?

Comment: don't think so, because whenever Consumer from DC1 commits offsets(after consuming message) I can see activity across DC2 _consumer_offset topic with new offsets and metadata for that consumer.

Comment: Note: This isn't really a good idea to copy the offsets topic as the offsets of clusterA are in no way guaranteed to be the same on clusterB. Plus, MirrorMaker has no exactly once guarantees

Comment: I agree with that but I don't know any other solution to reset consumer offsets to a certain point in time per partition on DC2(backup cluster) without manual intervention during disaster recovery.  And thus, I thought replicating _consumer_offsets topic would be a good solution.

Comment: @cricket_007 This issue should be resolved by MirrorMaker 2.0, correct? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0
Where mirror-maker script by default start syncing consumer offsets across clusters?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Mirror Maker 2.0 they say explicitly on the motivation that there is no support for exactly-once:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0#KIP-382:MirrorMaker2.0-Motivation

But they intend to do it in the future.