# How to migrate consumer offsets using MirrorMaker 2.0?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

With Kafka 2.7.0, I am using MirroMaker 2.0 as a Kafka-connect connector to replicate all the topics from the primary Kafka cluster to the backup cluster.

All the topics are being replicated perfectly except `__consumer_offsets`. Below are the connect configurations:

```json
{
    "name": "test-connector",
    "config": {
      "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
      "topics.blacklist": "some-random-topic",
      "replication.policy.separator": "",
      "source.cluster.alias": "",
      "target.cluster.alias": "",
      "exclude.internal.topics":"false",
      "tasks.max": "10",
      "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
      "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
      "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "xx.xx.xxx.xx:9094",
      "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "yy.yy.yyy.yy:9094",
      "topics": "test-topic-from-primary,primary-kafka-connect-offset,primary-kafka-connect-config,primary-kafka-connect-status,__consumer_offsets"
    }
}
```

In a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967654/kafka-mirror-maker-failing-to-replicate-consumer-offset-topic), the accepted answer says the following:

> Add this in your consumer.config:

> ***exclude.internal.topics=false***

> And add this in your producer.config:

> ***client.id=__admin_client***

Where do I add these in my configuration?

Here the [Connector Configuration Properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0#KIP382:MirrorMaker2.0-ConnectorConfigurationProperties) does not have such property named `client.id`, I have set the value of `exclude.internal.topics` to `false` though.

Is there something I am missing here?

## UPDATE

I learned that Kafka 2.7 and above supports automated consumer offset sync using `MirrorCheckpointTask` as mentioned [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-545%3A+support+automated+consumer+offset+sync+across+clusters+in+MM+2.0).

I have created a connector for this having the below configurations:

```json
{
    "name": "mirror-checkpoint-connector",
    "config": {
      "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector",
      "sync.group.offsets.enabled": "true",
      "source.cluster.alias": "",
      "target.cluster.alias": "",
      "exclude.internal.topics":"false",
      "tasks.max": "10",
      "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
      "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
      "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "xx.xx.xxx.xx:9094",
      "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "yy.yy.yyy.yy:9094",
      "topics": "__consumer_offsets"
    }
}
```

Still no help.
Is this the correct approach? Is there something needed?

Answer (score 2):

you do not want to replicate connsumer_offsets.  The offsets from the src to the destination cluster will not be the same for various reasons.

MirrorMaker2 provides the ability to do offset translation.  It will populate the destination cluster with a translated offset generated from the src cluster.  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-545%3A+support+automated+consumer+offset+sync+across+clusters+in+MM+2.0

Comment: So in order to achieve this, all I need to do is add `"sync.group.offsets.enabled" : "true"` to the config?

Comment: Yes.  In Kafka release 2.7 and later.

Comment: I am using Kafka 2.7.0 but this did not work for me. I have `"topics": "test-topic,__consumer_offsets"`, in this one `test-topic` is being replicated but `__consumer_offsets` is being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

__consumer_offsets is ignored by default

```
topics.exclude = [.*[\-\.]internal, .*\.replica, __.*]
```

you'll need to override this config